# How to fix zipper?

Tags: clothing

The zipper on my school bag is stuck. Is there any way to fix zippers on bags, clothes, etc.?
[image: For example :-]

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks! Can you clarify *how* the zipper is stuck? A picture would also be very useful. Thank you!

Comment: @michaelpri yes, that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use scissors to tighten up the zipper.

You need to make sure it's tight enough to bring the sliders together.

When it is too damaged your only option is to replace the whole zipper part.

Answer (score 0):

The zipper goes bad when

1. the handle bends/abrading, or
2. the zip is abrading

Most of the cases the handle can be squeezed a bit with pinchers and put some wax on the zip also can help.

But these are temporary solutions, the whole zipper needed to replace by a seamstress as soon as possible.